# Delete node in binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I got a segmentation fault when trying to print tree after node's deletion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree {
    int val;
    struct tree *left, *right;
} tree;

void insert (tree **root, int val) {
    tree *new_node, *parrent, *cur;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
    if (!*root)
        *root = new_node;
    else {
        cur = *root;
        while (cur) {
            parrent = cur;
            if (cur->val > val)
                cur = cur->left;
            else
                cur = cur->right;
        }
        if (parrent->val > val)
            parrent->left = new_node;
        else
            parrent->right = new_node;
    }
}

tree *search (tree *root, int val) {
    if (!root)
        return root;
    while (root && root->val != val) {
        if (root->val > val)
            root = root->left;
        else
            root = root->right;
    }
    return root;
}

void delete (tree **node) {
    tree *tmp;
    if (!(*node)->left) {
        tmp = *node;
        *node = (*node)->right;
        free(tmp);
    }
    else if (!(*node)->right) {
        tmp = *node;
        *node = (*node)->left;
        free(tmp);
    }
    else {
        for (tmp = (*node)->left; tmp->right; tmp = tmp->right)
            continue;
        tmp->right = (*node)->right;
        tmp = *node;
        *node = (*node)->left;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void preorderTraversal (tree *root) {
    if (root) {
        printf("%d\n", root->val);
        preorderTraversal(root->left);
        preorderTraversal(root->right);
    }
}

int main () {
    tree *root = NULL, *node;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        insert(&root, i);
    preorderTraversal(root);
    node = search(root, 3);
    delete(&node);
    preorderTraversal(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation was successful, compiler didn't show any warnings.

```
gcc tree.c -Wall -g -o tree
```

Algorithm in a few words: If a node has only one child, we change the value of the node to the value of its child, which does not break the tree. If a node has two children, we look for the maximum node in the subtree of the left node and change its right value to the right node value. Then we make the node equal to the value of the left node, which also doesn't break the tree.

---

P.S - The algorithm seems correct, but implementation may be wrong. Also I didn't know how to fulfill tree and choose consistent values, which probably is not good idea, but deletion operation should work for even example.

Comment: General advice in advance: Prefer `new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node))` – this is more robust against exchanging the type of `new_node` if you ever need to. Sure, not here, but in the future in other projects you might, and it never hurts learning good practice right from the start ;)

Comment: And where do you adjust the *parent* of a node? That one still has a pointer to the now deleted node! To consider, too: What happens, if you delete the root of your tree? I personally would rather consider `bool delete(tree** root, int value)` with the boolean (from `stdbool.h`) indicating if the value has been found at all.

Comment: OT (a bit): By inserting values in ascending sequence, the tree is actually no more than a linked list...

Comment: By the way, your simple tree implementation produces an entirely degenerate tree (a linked list actually) if inserting already sorted data. Extending on my previous comment: In your concrete example you first lookup the node with value 3 – and receive a pointer to. It is child of node with value 2 (!) – now you update the pointer `node` (declared in main) to the appropriate successor, but not the node in the tree with value 2!

Comment: `for( long x = 57428931; x; x /= 10 ) insert( &root, x%10 );` will insert into the tree several single digit values. You can experiment with jumbling the numbers...

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your `delete` method.

Consider the following example tree structure.

```
             +--------------------+                        
             |    Node: 0x0000    |                        
           +-|       val: 2       |-+                      
           | | l:0x0001 r: 0x0002 | |                      
           v +--------------------+ v                      
+--------------------+   +--------------------+            
|    Node: 0x0001    |   |    Node: 0x0002    |            
|       val: 1       |   |       val: 3       |-+          
|  l: null r: null   |   | l: null r: 0x0003  | |          
+--------------------+   +--------------------+ v          
                                     +--------------------+
                                     |    Node: 0x0003    |
                                     |       val: 4       |
                                     |  l: null r: null   |
                                     +--------------------+
```

If you have a pointer to node `0x0002`, and you call delete, this will:

1. Test that `l` of `Node 0x0002` is null, so it will enter the first `if` condition
2. Assign the values inside `Node 0x0003` to `Node 0x0002`
   After this step, the tree will look like this:

```
             +--------------------+                        
             |    Node: 0x0000    |                        
           +-|       val: 2       |-+                      
           | | l:0x0001 r: 0x0002 | |                      
           v +--------------------+ v                      
+--------------------+   +--------------------+            
|    Node: 0x0001    |   |    Node: 0x0002    |            
|       val: 1       |   |       val: 4       |            
|  l: null r: null   |   |  l: null r: null   |            
+--------------------+   +--------------------+            
                                     +--------------------+
                                     |    Node: 0x0003    |
                                     |       val: 4       |
                                     |  l: null r: null   |
                                     +--------------------+
```

Notice how there is no longer a pointer to `Node 0x0003`.

3. Call `free` on `Node 0x0002`. After this step, the tree will look like this:

```
             +--------------------+                        
             |    Node: 0x0000    |                        
           +-|       val: 2       |-+                      
           | | l:0x0001 r: 0x0002 | |                      
           v +--------------------+ |                      
+--------------------+              |                      
|    Node: 0x0001    |              +->                    
|       val: 1       |                                     
|  l: null r: null   |                                     
+--------------------+                                     
                                     +--------------------+
                                     |    Node: 0x0003    |
                                     |       val: 4       |
                                     |  l: null r: null   |
                                     +--------------------+
```

Notice that `Node 0x0000` is pointing to empty space, where `Node 0x0002` was (before you deleted it). Separately, `Node 0x0003` is now isolated, and will leak memory.

To fix this, as commenters noted, you need to either:

1. update the parent of the deleted node to point to the new child. This would mean setting `Node 0x0000`'s r value to `0x0003` in our example
2. Instead of freeing the deleted node, free the child In our example, this would mean deleting `Node 0x0003` after the assignment.

Comment: "Assign the values inside Node 0x0003 to Node 0x0002" The code doesn't do that, it only assigns pointers.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me. Could you look for my new program, please

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok, now?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree {
    int val;
    struct tree *left, *right, *parrent;
} tree;

void insert (tree **root, int val) {
    tree *new_node, *parrent, *cur;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
    if (!*root)
        *root = new_node;
    else {
        cur = *root;
        while (cur) {
            parrent = cur;
            if (cur->val > val)
                cur = cur->left;
            else
                cur = cur->right;
        }
        if (parrent->val > val)
            parrent->left = new_node;
        else
            parrent->right = new_node;
        new_node->parrent = parrent;
    }
}

tree *search (tree *root, int val) {
    if (!root)
        return root;
    while (root && root->val != val) {
        if (root->val > val)
            root = root->left;
        else
            root = root->right;
    }
    return root;
}

void delete (tree **node) {
    tree *tmp;
    if (!(*node)->left) {
        tmp = *node;
        if ((*node)->parrent->left == (*node))
            (*node)->parrent->left = (*node)->right;
        else
            (*node)->parrent->right = (*node)->right;
    }
    else if (!(*node)->right) {
        tmp = *node;
        if ((*node)->parrent->left == *node)
            (*node)->parrent->left = (*node)->left;
        else
            (*node)->parrent->right = (*node)->left;
    }
    else {
        for (tmp = (*node)->left; tmp->right; tmp = tmp->right)
            continue;
        tmp->right = (*node)->right;
        tmp = *node;
        if ((*node)->parrent->left == *node)
            (*node)->parrent->left = (*node)->left;
        else
            (*node)->parrent->right = (*node)->left;
    }
    free(tmp);
}

void preorderTraversal (tree *root) {
    if (root) {
        printf("%d\n", root->val);
        preorderTraversal(root->left);
        preorderTraversal(root->right);
    }
}

int main () {
    tree *root = NULL, *node;
    //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        // insert(&root, -i);
    for( long x = 57428931; x; x /= 10 ) 
        insert( &root, x%10 );
    preorderTraversal(root);
    node = search(root, 3);
    delete(&node);
    preorderTraversal(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post updates as answers. Instead, edit your question.